# Viewport issue, wrong width of the site on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

This website is currently having a problem on the viewport, and only happen on mobile:

http://www.samsungupdate.com/

Please use your mobile to visit the site, it always leaves a big gap on the right. But the problem isn't there on PC, when resizing the browser to smaller size.

I put user-scallable=no in the meta, but it still doesn't solve the problem (currently it's removed). Can anybody do a debug and explain why this happened?

Thank you.

Comment: What meta tag are you using (Other than that scallable one)?

Comment: In a quick inspect I think the problem is on the search or in the header

Comment: @Paulie_D Hi, I only use this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: @LuisP.A. Thank you, I think so too, but it seems it's impossible for me to debug them since they don't happen in PC.

Comment: @Tsuki . Awaits you a long work of trial and error. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styling doesn't look good but to make the gap go away get rid of the `padding: 0 25px` on top-header and on `only screen and (max-width: 479px)` get rid of `padding-left: 80px`.

Comment: I removed the 2 things already, but the problem still there. It's hard to debug, especially when this doesn't seem to happen everytime.

Comment: I'm using nexus 4 mobile device and the problem is gone. @Tsuki

Comment: I also just tested on the iphone 5 and works as well.

Comment: Make sure you cleared the browser cache. @Tsuki To get the latest of your stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah you're right :) However there is still a strange problem... I'm able to drag the whole website to the left & right. It looks like the scaling is now correct but the gap is still there.

Comment: Sorry, @Tsuki But, I'm not experiencing this on my phones. I'm unable to scroll left or right. Only able to scroll up and down.

Comment: It seems there are some unnecessary things left on header. However, thank you for your tips that made me free after nearly a week of trials & errors :-)

Comment: Your Welcome. Good luck with everything.